# How do I properly pass EditText (in 1st activity that creates a TextView in 2nd activity) to a third activity as TextView?

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-edittext

I have a Login button that when pressed sends the user to another activity and will post users name in TextView. That part is working fine. The trouble is when I try to pass the username that is in the second activity TextView on to a third activity TextView it doesn't show up. The android:hint shows up as text so I know the xml is fine. I've tried every kind of "putExtra" intent I could find on this site. I think I just missed something..Help. I'm totally new to android so laugh at the newbie :)

ACTIVITY 2

```
  public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
UserFunctions userFunctions;
Button btnLogout;
Button scanButton;
Button userinfo;
Button help;
Button receipt;
TextView showmsg;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**
     * Dashboard Screen for the application
     * */        
    // Check login status in database
    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);



        scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        userinfo =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.userinfo);
        help =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);
        receipt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.receipt);
        showmsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showmsg);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        if (in.getCharSequenceExtra("usr") != null) {
            final TextView setmsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showmsg);
            setmsg.setText("User: "+in.getCharSequenceExtra("usr"));                
        }




        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(login);
                // Closing dashboard screen
                finish();
            }
        });


        // Link to CC
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MyScanActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Create a customer receipt
        receipt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, ReceiptActivity.class));
                intent.putExtra("TextView",showmsg);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Link to User info
        userinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        UserInfoActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // Link to Help info
        help.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        HelpActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });



    }else{
        // user is not logged in show login screen
        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(login);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
    }




}
```

}

Comment: Why don't you just pass the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SmulianJulian:

There is a mistake. You re passing the component **TextView** to next intent, while you should be passing it's text only.

You are currently doing this :

```
intent.putExtra("TextView",showmsg);
```

but you should do it like

```
Bundle extras = myIntent.getExtras();
 extras .putString("TextView",showmsg.getText().toString());
```

and in 3rd activity you should get this value like :

```
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
bundle.getString("TextView");
```

and then set this value into your textview.

```
TextView yourTV = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id));
yourTV.setText(bundle.getString("TextView"));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

after login , try to save the username in `SharedPreferences` ,and then you can get it's value wherever and whenever you want :

Saving username :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("username", username).commit();
```

Retrieving the value of username from yourActivity :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String username = prefs.getString("username");
yourTextView.setText(username);
```